# Why are there weird texture artifacts in baked light which don't appear with realtime light?

Tags: unity, lighting

This is the comparison of the same scene, realtime light vs baked light.

What's am I wrong ?

EDIT: In particular, also texture are low quality (see image 2). Why ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know you're probably most worried about the fact your baked light seems blue, but I just wanted to point out that in the realtime light image, you can clearly see some specular lighting, which is highly dependent on the observer's position. Therefore, it cannot be baked into a texture.

Comment: I have seen similar artifacts when I started the game before the lights finished baking. Did you wait until the progress bar in the lower right corner of the Unity editor is finished?

Comment: Yes, all baking i've tried finishes...

Answer (score 2):

I solved: what I miss was not to follow this:

"Make sure any Mesh you want to apply a light map to has proper UVs for lightmapping. The easiest way to do this is to open the Mesh import settings and enable the Generate Lightmap UVs setting."

[enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lightmapping.html)

Comment: If this fixed the issue, you may consider marking it as accepted!